# Wrong language in App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, app-store, info.plist

Okay, it seems I am missing something...

Made an app in Dutch and in the info.plist I set "Localization native development region" to "nl"

[image: Info.plist]

plus I added the correct development language in localisation:

[image: localisation]

In iTunes Connect I only have one language, Dutch as primary.

But in the App Store and iTunes it says the app language is in English.

What am I forgetting or doing wrong here?

Comment: development region might be different than deployment region. Is there a setting for language/region in the build phases or build settings? Not a Mac at hand right now, so can't check for myself.